# Truncate text to get preview in Scala

Tags: string, scala

I need to truncate a text to get a *preview*. The preview is the text prefix of ~`N` chars (but not more) and it should not split words in the middle.

```
preview("aaa", 10) = "aaa"
preview("a b c", 10) = "a b c"
preview("aaa bbb", 5) = "aaa"
preview("a b ccc", 3) = "a b"
```

I coded a function as follows:

```
def preview(s:String, n:Int) =
  if (s.length <= n) s else s.take(s.lastIndexOf(' ', n))
```

Would you change or fix it ?

Now I am thinking how to handle the case when the text words are separated by one or more white spaces (including `\n`,`\t`, etc.) rather than just a single space. How would you improve the function to handle this case ?

Comment: what would you expect it to do for `preview("aaaaa bbbbb cc", 7)` or `preview("aaaaa", 3)`?

Comment: `preview("aaaaa bbbbb cc", 7)` should return `"aaaaa"`, `preview("aaaaa", 3)` -- `"aaa"`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about the following:

```
  def preview(s: String, n: Int) = if (s.length <= n) {
    s
  } else {
    s.take(s.lastIndexWhere(_.isSpaceChar, n + 1)).trim
  }
```

This function will:

- For the strings shorter or equal `n` return the string (no preview required)
- Otherwise find the the last space character in the `n + 1` first characters (this will indicate whether the last world is being split, as if it's not than `n + 1` will be a space chracter and otherwise a non-space character) and take a string up to this point

Note: The usage of [isSpaceChar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isSpaceChar%28char%29) will not only provide support for space, but also new line or paragraph, which is what I believe you're after (and you can replace it with `isWhitespace` if you're after even more extended set of word separators).

Answer (score 2):

I propose next one:

**-- UPDATED--**

```
def ellipsize(text : String, max : Int): String = {
  def ellipsize0(s : String): String =
    if(s.length <= max) s
    else {
      val end = s.lastIndexOf(" ")
      if(end == -1) s.take(max)
      else ellipsize0(s.take(end))
    }
  ellipsize0("\\s+".r.replaceAllIn(text, " "))
}
```

Or your (modified):

```
def preview(str : String, n : Int) = { 
  (s : String) => if (s.length <= n) s else s.take(s.lastIndexOf(' ', n))
}.apply( "\\s+".r.replaceAllIn(str, " "))
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this

```
def preview(s:String, n:Int) =
  if (s.length <= n) s 
  else s.take(n).takeWhile(_ != ' ')
```

Try it here: http://scalafiddle.net/console/a05d886123a54de3ca4b0985b718fb9b

Comment: Have you tested it on `preview("a b ccc", 3) = "a b"`?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
  // find the last word that is not split by n, then take to its end
  def preview(text: String, n: Int): String = 
    text take (("""\S+""".r findAllMatchIn text takeWhile (_.end <= n)).toList match {
      case Nil => n
      case ms  => ms.last.end
    })
```

An alternative take (pun intended) but doesn't like input of all whitespace:

```
text take (("""\S+""".r findAllMatchIn text takeWhile (m => m.start == 0 || m.end <= n)).toList.last.end min n)
```

Extensionally:

```
object Previewer {
  implicit class `string preview`(val text: String) extends AnyVal {
    // find the last word that is not split by n, then take to its end
    def preview(n: Int): String =
      text take (("""\S+""".r findAllMatchIn text takeWhile (_.end <= n)).toList match {
        case Nil => n
        case ms  => ms.last.end
      })
  }
}
```

Looks nice that way:

```
class PreviewTest {
  import Previewer._

  @Test def shorter(): Unit = {
    assertEquals("aaa", "aaa" preview 10)
  } 
  @Test def spacey(): Unit = {
    assertEquals("a b c", "a b c" preview 10)
  }
  @Test def split(): Unit = { 
    assertEquals("abc", "abc cba" preview 5)
  }   
  @Test def onspace(): Unit = {
    assertEquals("a b", "a b cde" preview 3)
  } 
  @Test def trimming(): Unit = {
    assertEquals("a b", "a b    cde" preview 5)
  } 
  @Test def none(): Unit = {
    assertEquals(" " * 5, " " * 8 preview 5)
  }
  @Test def prefix(): Unit = {
    assertEquals("a" * 5, "a" * 10 preview 5)
  } 
}
```